# Sql Server Queries taking time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-performance

I am facing some issues with my stored procedures.

I am having 1 stored procedure for a Stack Bar graph, showing one months data.

Earlier on my local server it was taking more than 40 seconds, so I made some changes and now it takes 4 seconds. The same query when I run on my live server takes more than 40 seconds.

The count of the records are the same as in my local server.

Can anybody tell me what I should do to make it more fast on my live server?

Comment: Umm. replicate the changes you made on the local server?

Comment: Have you tried using Indexes on the tables?

Comment: Not enough information - we need **at least**: table structure, information about indexes, the **exact** query, data distribution (what kind of data is in that table) .......

Comment: I guess the same symtoms applicable for Paramer Sniffing. Refer:[link](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/)

Comment: On top of that : do an `EXEC sp_updatestats` on your database(s); it might well be your statistics are out of date and the server is choosing incorrect query plans because of that.

Answer (score 1):

A good start is to run SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), load up the query, and switch on 'Display Actual Execution Plan', this will show you exactly what SQL is doing with your query. It will also show you a relative '%cost' in relation to the steps in the query. This helps to identify which table/join/aggregate whatever is causing the query to take so long.

I also believe that in the latest version of SSMS it advises which indexes should be added.

Hope this helps.
Rich.

Comment: i have cleared my log file for that db on the server. but this is the temporary solution i knw. after few days again i have to go there n do this again. give me some permanent solution plz

Comment: clearing your log file will help in the short term, but it's not addressing your main issue. Did you try as I suggested above? If you view the execution plan, it might point out something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated question . It's a lot of parameters 
Can change time of execution

CPU speed,
Ram,
Indexes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming server will be more powerful in terms of processing power and RAM, indexes is something you would like to look into.

Comment: My table cotains more than 10000 records. so putting indexing now will effect the performance?

Comment: yes, it will make everything much faster =)
Adding the actual index takes only little time. Just make sure to put a RELEVANT index there. (to answer your next question : it depends)

Comment: BTW, can u paste sample query because it takes 40s on just 10k records, it has lots of scope for performance improvement.

Answer (score -1):

use indexes with your mysql tables and also it may be because of your hosting **server's performance**. The server may be faced with **down time**.